# How are the web worker files loaded?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I want to emit something to the web-worker right after it was loaded. The code looks like:

```
var w = new Worker("worker.js");
w.onmessage = function (ev) {
    console.log(ev.data);
};
w.postMessage("Hello World");
```

In `worker.js` I have:

```
this.onmessage = function (ev) {
    self.postMessage(ev.data);
}
```

So, the event flow is like this:

> window --`Hello World`-> web worker -- `Hello World` ->  window -> `console.log(ev.data)`

My question is why does this work? That means the `worker.js` file was loaded synchronously. Is that correct?

I even tried loading other files in the web worker:

```
importScripts('foo.js');
importScripts('bar.js');
```

Even loading these files work fine. Why? How are the web worker files loaded, from a low-level perspective?

Comment: Message passing is asynchronous. Every JS environment has its own event queue.

Comment: _"My question is why does this work?"_ Not certain interpret Question correctly ? _"How are the web worker files loaded"_ `Worker` could also be loaded from `js` present on same page , without reference to an "external" "file" . See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: @Bergi I know, but I was asking bout loading the worker file. Is that sync or async (`new Worker("worker.js")`)? It seems to be sync.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: Sync, yes, but in the new webworker thread. It does immediately return a `Worker` object. The constructor does not wait for the file to be loaded.

Comment: @Bergi OK, and is it possible to emit from the main window something before the file itself is loaded? If not, is there a `load` event or so I can listen to and *be sure* the worker is listening for events? I had a similar issue with postmessage api using iframes.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: You *are* calling `.postMessage` before the file is loaded, and it does work fine. Each worker has its own message queue as I said.

Comment: @Bergi I've got it! Post an answer! Having some docs/source-code would be appreciated as well!

Comment: @IonicăBizău: guest271314 already linked those…

Answer (score 0):

`new Worker("worker.js")` does not “network-block” the calling thread (“main thread”). The `new` call returns independent of the state of the worker. The worker might not yet be done with executing its script, with loading its script, or even initializing itself to the state where it can start/order the loading of its script.

Your following `onmessage` is set up in the main thread independent of the worker state. That does not block either.

The `postMessage()` call will queue a message for the worker without waiting for its pickup. At this point the main thread is done executing (“fell through the bottom”) and its event loop will be waiting for events.

The worker runs independent of the main thread (well... that is the whole point of creating a worker). It will first run through its worker script. Right now I can’t think of any way for it to (temporarily) yield execution, which means that the whole worker script needs to “fall through the bottom”, i.e. finish execution before the worker’s individual event loop is given control (again).

Only then the message from the main thread will be picked up by Javascript when it runs the worker thread’s event loop. Your worker’s `onmessage()` function will be called, which queues a message to the main thread. That message might already be picked up by the main thread even before the worker’s `postMessage()` completes. (Of course, that might also happen on the other way around, if the worker is idle.)

Intermediate `importScripts()` in the worker are synchronous and block the worker, not the main thread.

An alternative to synchronous blocking `importScripts()` are module workers with `new Worker('worker.js', {type: 'module'})`. Those replace `importScripts()` with asynchronous `import()` or synchronous `import`. Few browsers support that as of now. Blink does, but for Opera I don’t know how it can support [module worker](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_worker_worker_ecmascript_modules) without [import in worker](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_statements_import_worker_support).

(For more try this [module worker article](https://web.dev/module-workers/).)

Comment: You are missing the most important part in OP's confusion: The Worker instance has its own MessagePorts which will get entangled only when the worker context is started ([step 18 here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#worker-processing-model)). The messages are still *stored* by the main context until that point. And it's also per specs (same section) that it's defined the port is not open nor the event loop started before the script is ran.